# Error using N1QL in Couchbase Server

Tags: couchbase, nosql

I'm using Couchbase 4.0 community editionm and trying to perform simple N1QL operations in my couchbase server,
using those GET requests:

simple "`select 1`" statement:
[http://localhost:8093/query?statement=SELECT%201](http://localhost:8093/query?statement=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20cache)

AND

http://localhost:8093/query?statement=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20cache

(where `cache` is my bucket name)

For any request i'm sending, I get the following error:

```
{
    "requestID": "30096327-05eb-4282-b170-7601f6118aac",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 1120,
            "msg": "Unsupported media type: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
        }
    ],
    "status": "fatal",
    "metrics": {
        "elapsedTime": "0",
        "executionTime": "0",
        "resultCount": 0,
        "resultSize": 0,
        "errorCount": 1
    }
}
```

What can be the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your user agent (web browser?) is requesting a media type which isn't supported by the query engine - the user agent is requesting a variation of HTML.

Try using something like a command-line HTTP client (CuRL, wget etc).

Comment: You right. I'm using Google Chrome version 46.0 .
Is there any way fixing it in the browser ?

Comment: you can use a Chrome extension that provides a GUI to make HTTP requests similar to what curl does: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop